# Cannot change to 2K resolution in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (but I can in Xorg)

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, display-resolution, wayland

I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS in my laptop with an integrated Intel HD 620 graphic card. I have connected via HDMI a 2K monitor with a 144 Hz refresh rate but I cannot change to the 2560x1440 resolution. I already tried it in Windows and had no problem.

I followed the answer to [Can't set 2560x1440 resolution on Ubuntu 20.04 with Intel Graphics Card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294846/cant-set-2560x1440-resolution-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-graphics-card) but got this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)  
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)  
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)  
  Value in failed request:  0x0   
  Serial number of failed request:  22  
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Reading a bit more I encountered this thread: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399525&p=13812525#post13812525. Looking at my xorg logs I found out that the 2560x1440 mode was listed:

```
[  4539.428] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  4539.428] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "2560x1440"x0.0  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync +vsync (88.8 kHz e)
```

The vsync polarity was actually opposite to what I found with `cvt`.
I added this mode with `xrandr` but it still did not work (same error appeared).

On a whim, I tried the same thing on Ubuntu with Xorg and it actually worked!
I tried to find out in my logs if it was a Wayland problem but could not find anything, nor in other threads. I also tried, when using Wayland, to use the Xorg name for the monitor as I saw in another thread (that for some reason I cannot find again, sorry), but it did not work.

Of course there is always the possibility to use Xorg, but it would not be ideal. Has someone got an idea how to solve this? Am I missing something obvious?

I am happy to give any additional info. Thanks in advance!