# Can't set QHD resoltion to external monitor using xrandr

Tags: 22.04, display, intel-graphics, xrandr, wayland

I have gotten a new QHD monitor and I want to connect it to my laptop. The monitor is already tested and working in that resolution with the same HDMI cable I am using here.

I have `Dell Inc. Vostro 15 3510` with `11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8` and `Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)` and Linux distro is `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`.

I tried to accomplish this by adding a new ModeLine to a monitor using `xrandr`.

Here is the output what I have done and the error  have encounter:

```
maricevic@maricevic-Vostro-15-3510:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  60.00    48.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  

maricevic@maricevic-Vostro-15-3510:~$ cvt 2560 1440
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

maricevic@maricevic-Vostro-15-3510:~$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

maricevic@maricevic-Vostro-15-3510:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "2560x1440_60.00"

maricevic@maricevic-Vostro-15-3510:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.00 +  60.00    48.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
  2560x1440_60.00 (0x7c6) 312.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.96Hz

maricevic@maricevic-Vostro-15-3510:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "2560x1440_60.00"
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

Same happens if I go to display settings and select that option, instead of last command, it "changes" the res, but it actually stays the same.
After this, i can't get it working.

Before doing this, I had to switch to use Xorg instead of Wayland, because with wayland i could get that option created. It would be shown in `xrandr` command, but not visible in display setting. If I would try to select it with `xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00`, I would get something like this (not exactly, but similar, because i am too lazy to reproduce):

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check/test:

Look at `dmesg` output when you get the `xrandr` error - e.g. run `sudo dmesg -w` in another terminal window. To see if that gives any more information about the error.

Are you getting this when using the Laptop monitor AND the external monitor. If so try when just using the external monitor.

Try generating your modeline by using `cvt` command with reduced blanking mode e.g. `cvt -r 2560 1440` or alternatively specify a reduced refresh rate lower than the default 60 e.g. `cvt 2560 1440 30`. I know you don't want a refresh rate of 30 but it may help to diagnose the issue if it's related to pixel dotclock issues.

Run `xrandr --verbose` and see what `CRTCs` are listed for HDMI-1. Probably 0, 1, 2 so then try specifying a different crtc 2 on your output line, e.g.:

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --crtc 2 --mode "2560x1440_60.00"`

Comment: Setting the lower refresh rate with cvt 2560 1440 30 worked, but using -r flag resulted in same error.
Also i have 0, 1, 2, 3 listed for CRTCs, and i get the same error for all of them:  xrandr: Configure crtc <0-3> failed

Comment: So it seems to me like a pixel clock issue your `cvt` results in `pclk: 312.25 MHz` which is too high, and even `cvt -r` results in `pclk: 241.50 MHz` which again must be too high. Why this is the case and why Ubuntu is not listing the additional modes I cannot answer right now. See the post and accepted answer here for similar issue and possibly some more information, maybe you can determine from the logs hat your pixel clock limit is: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294846/cant-set-2560x1440-resolution-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-graphics-card