# Dell Inspirion External Ultrawide Monitor (HDMI) Limited Resolution at 1920 x 1200

Tags: dell, display-resolution, hdmi, external-monitor

There are numerous reports from owners of certain Dell laptop models who are unable to operate ultrawide external monitors at their full resolution via HDMI output. In such cases, the resolution is limited to either 1920 x 1080 or 1900 x 1200. In my situation, I cannot achieve the resolution of 2560 x 1080 on my LG 29WK600 ultrawide monitor connected to my Dell Inspiron 15 3520.

Indeed, there is a [note](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/pt-br/000126548/resolution-on-external-monitor-limited-to-1920-x-1080-using-hdmi?lang=en) on Dell's own website with a list of laptops that have this limitation.

A curious fact is that some owners reported a solution for Windows 11 users, involving the use of an older driver, version 30.0.101.1338. In Dell's Portuguese-speaking community, several users claim to have resolved the issue after installing this driver version, which can be found [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/pt-br/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=m83m4).

However, I have not found any solution for Linux users. In my case, my external monitor's resolution (HDMI) remains limited to 1920 x 1080 instead of 2560 x 1080. I have attempted adjustment procedures using `xrandr`, but without success.

I imagine that if a solution was found using proprietary drivers for Windows, it should be possible for Linux users as well.

Thanks for any assistance!

---

Some info:

> Laptop Dell Inspirion 15 3520 Ubuntu 23.10 Memory 16 Gb Processor 11th
> Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 × 8 Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)

**Kernel**

```
  uname -r
    6.5.0-13-generic
```

**xrandr**

```
xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 340mm
   1920x1080     59.88*+
   1440x1080     59.87  
   1400x1050     59.86  
   1280x1024     59.76  
   1280x960      59.79  
   1152x864      59.78  
   1024x768      59.68  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.85  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x720      59.75  
   960x600       59.63  
   928x580       59.88  
   800x500       59.50  
   768x480       59.38  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.20  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.82  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.45  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080    120.17*+
   1440x1080    120.14  
   1400x1050    120.13  
   1280x1024    120.09  
   1280x960     120.02  
   1152x864     120.11  
   1024x768     120.02  
   800x600      119.85  
   640x480      119.52  
   320x240      119.73  
   1680x1050    120.08  
   1440x900     120.20  
   1280x800     120.18  
   1152x720     119.94  
   960x600      120.04  
   928x580      119.87  
   800x500      119.91  
   768x480      119.71  
   720x480      119.65  
   640x400      119.64  
   320x200      117.55  
   1600x900     120.18  
   1368x768     119.99  
   1280x720     120.04  
   1024x576     120.15  
   864x486      120.10  
   720x400      119.54  
   640x350      120.03
```

**lspci**

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [1028:0bb2]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

**glxinfo**

```
glxinfo -B
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) (0x9a49)
    Version: 39497.1.8
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 15708MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.0~git2312040600.38ce0c~oibaf~m (git-38ce0c1 2023-12-04 mantic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0~git2312040600.38ce0c~oibaf~m (git-38ce0c1 2023-12-04 mantic-o
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.0~git2312040600.38ce0c~oibaf~m (git-38ce0c1 2023-12-04 mantic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

**lshw**

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       descrição: VGA compatible controller
       produto: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 2
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
       nome lógico: /dev/fb0
       versão: 01
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuração: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       recursos: memória de E/S:600-5ff memória de E/S:400-3ff irq:138 memória:6000000000-6000ffffff memória:4000000000-400fffffff porta de E/S:4000(tamanho=64) memória:c0000-dffff memória:4010000000-4016ffffff memória:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Comment: There was a very similar issue on here recently which has some info and links to other posts that may be useful. That issue looked like a pixel dotclock issue as the OP could set to the desired resolution with a lower refresh rate, not the full/expected refresh rate. May be worth reading and trying the same suggestions I suggested? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493417/cant-set-qhd-resoltion-to-external-monitor-using-xrandr/1493966#1493966

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! I followed xrand sequence and set cvt rate in 30 Hz instead of 60 Hz. It works. It is not a preferable way running just 30 Hz, but it is some solution for my widescreen use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a not perfect solution, but, in my case, it is a reasonable one. My ultrawide screen is full (2560 x 1080), except its rate which is running under 30 Hz and not the expected 60 Hz.

In my case, it is not work in Wayland, just in xorg mode.

It is the sequence:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    120.21*+ 120.21    60.21  
   1680x1050    120.21  
   1400x1050    120.21  
   1600x900     120.21  
   1280x1024    120.21  
   1400x900     120.21  
   1280x960     120.21  
   1368x768     120.21  
   1280x800     120.21  
   1152x864     120.21  
   1280x720     120.21  
   1024x768     120.21  
   1024x768i    120.21  
   960x720      120.21  
   928x696      120.21  
   896x672      120.21  
   1024x576     120.21  
   960x600      120.21  
   832x624      120.21  
   960x540      120.21  
   800x600      120.21  
   840x525      120.21  
   864x486      120.21  
   700x525      120.21  
   800x450      120.21  
   640x512      120.21  
   700x450      120.21  
   640x480      120.21  
   720x405      120.21  
   720x400      120.21  
   684x384      120.21  
   640x400      120.21  
   576x432      120.21  
   640x360      120.21  
   640x350      120.21  
   512x384      120.21  
   512x384i     120.21  
   512x288      120.21  
   416x312      120.21  
   480x270      120.21  
   400x300      120.21  
   432x243      120.21  
   320x240      120.21  
   360x202      120.21  
   360x200      120.21  
   320x200      120.21  
   320x180      120.21  
   320x175      120.21  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
igor@igor-inspiron-15-3520:~$ cvt 2560 1080 30
# 2560x1080 29.97 Hz (CVT) hsync: 33.03 kHz; pclk: 106.75 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_30.00"  106.75  2560 2640 2896 3232  1080 1083 1093 1102 -hsync +vsync
igor@igor-inspiron-15-3520:~$ xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_30.00"  106.75  2560 2640 2896 3232  1080 1083 1093 1102 -hsync +vsync
igor@igor-inspiron-15-3520:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 "2560x1080_30.00"
[sudo] senha para igor: 
igor@igor-inspiron-15-3520:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    120.21*+ 120.21    60.21  
   1680x1050    120.21  
   1400x1050    120.21  
   1600x900     120.21  
   1280x1024    120.21  
   1400x900     120.21  
   1280x960     120.21  
   1368x768     120.21  
   1280x800     120.21  
   1152x864     120.21  
   1280x720     120.21  
   1024x768     120.21  
   1024x768i    120.21  
   960x720      120.21  
   928x696      120.21  
   896x672      120.21  
   1024x576     120.21  
   960x600      120.21  
   832x624      120.21  
   960x540      120.21  
   800x600      120.21  
   840x525      120.21  
   864x486      120.21  
   700x525      120.21  
   800x450      120.21  
   640x512      120.21  
   700x450      120.21  
   640x480      120.21  
   720x405      120.21  
   720x400      120.21  
   684x384      120.21  
   640x400      120.21  
   576x432      120.21  
   640x360      120.21  
   640x350      120.21  
   512x384      120.21  
   512x384i     120.21  
   512x288      120.21  
   416x312      120.21  
   480x270      120.21  
   400x300      120.21  
   432x243      120.21  
   320x240      120.21  
   360x202      120.21  
   360x200      120.21  
   320x200      120.21  
   320x180      120.21  
   320x175      120.21  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   2560x1080_30.00  29.97  
igor@igor-inspiron-15-3520:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode "2560x1080_30.00"
```